sqlmodel many-to-many cascade
У меня есть две модели и промежуточная таблица, связанные отношением many-to-many.
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Relationship
...

class UserBlockLink(SQLModel, table=True):
    user_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key='user.id', primary_key=True)
    block_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key='block.id', primary_key=True)

class User(UserBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)
    blocks: list[Block] = Relationship(back_populates=None, link_model=UserBlockLink)
    
class Block(BlockBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)
    name: str
    questions: list['Question'] = Relationship(back_populates='block',
                                               sa_relationship_kwargs={"cascade": "all, delete"})


Я хочу чтобы при удалении User или Block происходило удаление записи из таблицы UserBlockLink, которая их связывает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это сделать похожим образом как происходит удаление Question при удалении Block, используя cascade?
Пробовал некоторые варианты, но они либо не работают, либо ошибка.
Последнее что прбовал заменить объявление полей таблицы UserBlockLink на вид:
Field(sa_column=Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete='CASCADE'), default=None, primary_key=True)) . Ошибки нет, но и удаление не происходит

На уровне SQL-сервера это делается элементарно. Вот, скажем, как это выглядит в случае использования MySQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/kq1mtHG3 Проверьте, работает ли аналогичный код так же в вашей СУБД. Если да, то смотрите, что создаёт по написанному коду фреймворк, и приводите результат его работы к показанному шаблону.

Выглядит так, как будто Field(sa_column=Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete='CASCADE'), default=None, primary_key=True)) это должно было сработать. Спасибо, посмотрю
